# How to call class constant getter function overload

Tags: c++, class, reference, constants, overloading

I have a class with 2 overload getter functions. One returns a reference and the other a constant reference. I would like to know the way to call the second function. Whatever I try to do, it always calls the first function.

```
class MyClass 
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> myArray = { 0, 10 };

    public:
              int& getElement()       { return myArray[0]; }
        const int& getElement() const { return myArray[1]; }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c;
    
    int& a       = c.getElement();
    const int& b = c.getElement();
    
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

result:

```
a = 0
b = 0
```

Comment: `const MyClass c; const int& b = c.getElement();` Return type has no bearing on which overloaded function is called.

Comment: `const int& b = static_cast<MyClass const&>(c).getElement();`

Comment: And of course `const MyClass c; int& a = c.getElement();` is a compile error.

Comment: Note that returning different values here definetly makes the class hard to use. Given the function signatures the only thing you'd expect to be different here is the constness of the value returned. Anything else makes the code hard to maintain. I assume in this case you're simply using this to tell the difference between the overload used.